# How should I implement NHibernate with OpenRasta?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, openrasta

Looking for a best practice type of thing, here. What should I do in OpenRasta to implement Fluent NHibernate, including proper session management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example project that I came across recently that uses OpenRasta, NHibernate, and FluentNHibernate: https://github.com/DveMac/OpenRasta.Forum The project uses the pattern of passing ISession into the constructor of a Repository instance. It uses StructureMap to control the lifecycle of the NHibernate session.